# local storage not updating array properly

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a function that updates a stringified array of objects in local storage. Although it works locally it does not work properly for local storage. Wat happens is the local storage array of objects is updated to the new value but the old value disappears. here is my code...

```
addSingleItem = (item) => {

const itemName = item.split("-")[0]; 
const itemDescription = item.split("-")[1];
const itemPrice = item.split("-")[2];

try {

    let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

    products.map((product, index) => { 

        if(product.name === itemName) { 
            products.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
            document.getElementsById(`itemName-${itemName}`).innerText = "Add To Cart";
            return;
        } 

    });

    products.push({
        name: itemName,
        description: itemDescription,
        price: itemPrice
    });

    localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
    document.getElementsById(`itemName-${itemName}`).innerText = "Remove From Cart";

} catch(err) {

    localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify([{ 
        name: itemName,
        description: itemDescription, 
        price: itemPrice 
    }]));

    document.getElementById(`itemName-${itemName}`).innerText = "Remove From Cart";

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "the local storage array of objects is updated to the new value but the old value disappears"? If you use the localStorage.setItem it will replace it with the new array. If you mean that it removes the item from the array and add new one at the end, it's because you use splice. Please show an example of the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

That is the way `localStorage` works. `localStorage.setItem()` does not add values to the existing key. It **overwrites** the existing `localStorage` key

If you want to append items instead of overwriting, you can use the following workaround:

```
let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
//I assume you stored something like this [{ name: "Apple", price: "10" }, { name: "Banana", price: "20" }]

//Then, if you want to add something:
products.push({ name: "Coffee", price: "140" });

//Then, localStorage.setItem("...", JSON.stringify(products));
```

When you edit `localStorage` variables you need to store the original value in a variable then, change variable values in a new variable, combine both and finally execute `setItem()` so that the old value also stays (if you want).

Comment: im doing this i am pretty sure. localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.strongify(products));